# Error When using Bazel to build the Android tensorflow_demo

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, bazel

Hello I am am building the Android tensorflow_demo with the command;
bazel build --cxxopt='--std=c++11' -c opt //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo.
However, I am seeing this error;
/Users/thremanehenry/tensorflowMaster/tensorflow/core/BUILD:321:1: Illegal ambiguous match on configurable attribute "copts" in //tensorflow/core:lib_proto_parsing:
//tensorflow:android
//tensorflow:macos

Have anyone seen or might know what is the meaning of this error please.